# How does pg_put_line know which table the data should be inserted into?

Tags: php

From [the API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-put-line.php):

```
<?php 
  $conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=foo");
  pg_query($conn, "create table bar (a int4, b char(16), d float8)");
  pg_query($conn, "copy bar from stdin");
  pg_put_line($conn, "3\thello world\t4.5\n");
  pg_put_line($conn, "4\tgoodbye world\t7.11\n");
  pg_put_line($conn, "\\.\n");
  pg_end_copy($conn);
?>
```

what if I have a table on my thomas schema that I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told it what table to write to in the previous line:

```
pg_query($conn, "copy bar from stdin");
```

Comment: so `"copy thomas.mytable from stdin"`?